# Нет перевода текста на странице регистрации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам текст:

> Opt-in to receive occasional Stack Overflow news, product updates, and
>   invitations to participate in user research. If you opt out, you will
>   still receive notifications and emails triggered by your account
>   activity.

И:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать "Подробнее", то тоже часть текста не переведено:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил недостающие переводы. Некоторые ссылки ниже:

- https://ru.traducir.win/string/11883
- https://ru.traducir.win/string/1546
- https://ru.traducir.win/string/11217
- https://ru.traducir.win/string/11213
- https://ru.traducir.win/string/11215

Предлагайте исправления/улучшения. Текст появится на сайте после подкачки и пересборки.